# eclipse android sdk update to v20 broke my install

Tags: android, eclipse

My AVD informed me of an update to v20. But after doing so I cannot use Eclipse for Android development any more.

When I try to use Help -> Check for updates:

[image: updates found]

and click *Next* I then get the error shown below. I can't see to find a way to fix this? I'm not verging on uninstalling eclipse and going from the ground up.

```
    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.jcraft.jsch,0.1.46.v201205102330
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.persistence,2.0.4.v201112161009
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.servlet,3.0.0.v201112011016
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.servlet.jsp,2.2.0.v201112011158
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.ant,1.8.3.v20120321-1730
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.lang,2.6.0.v201205030909
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.core,3.2.400.v20120523-1752
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.launching,1.0.200.v20120530-1204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.ui,3.5.300.v20120523-1752
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.compare,3.5.300.v20120522-1148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.compare.core,3.5.200.v20120522-1148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.compare.win32,1.0.200.v20120522-1148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.commands,3.6.1.v20120521-2329
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.contenttype,3.4.200.v20120523-2004
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.databinding,1.4.1.v20120521-2329
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans,1.2.200.v20120523-1955
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable,1.4.1.v20120521-2329
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.databinding.property,1.4.100.v20120523-1955
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.expressions,3.4.400.v20120523-2004
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.externaltools,1.0.100.v20120521-2012
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.filebuffers,3.5.200.v20120523-1310
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.filesystem,1.3.200.v20120522-2012
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86,1.1.300.v20120522-1137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.jobs,3.5.200.v20120521-2346
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.net,1.2.200.v20120522-1148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86,1.0.100.v20120522-1148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.resources,3.8.0.v20120522-2034
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86,3.5.100.v20120522-1137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.runtime,3.8.0.v20120521-2346
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility,3.2.200.v20120521-2346
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry,3.5.100.v20120521-2346
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.variables,3.2.600.v20120521-2012
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cvs,1.2.0.v201206081400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity,1.2.5.v201206130431
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design,3.3.5.v201204241156
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.ui,3.2.7.v201205221153
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.flatfile,3.1.2.v201206121559
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.flatfile.ui,3.1.3.v201203221637
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile,3.2.7.v201203291105
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core,1.2.5.v201205240353
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core.ui,1.2.2.v201205240353
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.server.ui,1.1.100.v201202021103
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui,1.2.3.v201205240353
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.iseries.ui,1.0.2.v201202100836
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.luw.ui,1.0.3.v201202100836
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.zseries.ui,1.0.2.v201202100836
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.informix.ui,1.0.3.v201202100836
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.msft.sqlserver.dbdefinition,1.0.1.v201201240505
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.mysql,1.0.3.v201205252211
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws,1.2.4.v201203221631
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws.ui,1.2.4.v201203221631
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oracle.dbdefinition,1.0.103.v201206010214
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.postgresql,1.1.1.v201205252207
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sqlite.dbdefinition,1.0.2.v201206010441
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.sql.query,1.1.3.v201206060918
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.editor.core,1.0.2.v201205310904
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query,1.2.1.v201201250511
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result,1.1.3.v201205310911
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqlscrapbook,1.0.2.v201205310922
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.debug.core,3.7.100.v20120521-2012
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.debug.ui,3.8.0.v20120530-1753
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.8.0.201206112118
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.dstore.core,3.3.100.201205300905
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.dstore.extra,2.1.400.201205300905
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf,3.1.300.v20120608-0148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer,5.0.0.v20120608-0148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.identity,3.1.200.v20120608-0148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer,3.2.0.v20120608-0148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient,4.0.200.v20120608-0148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.ssl,1.0.0.v20120608-0148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.ssl,1.0.0.v20120608-0148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.ssl,1.0.100.v20120608-0148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ant,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ui,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.8.0.v20120606-0717
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common.ui,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.converter,2.5.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.databinding,1.2.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.databinding.edit,1.2.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.8.0.v20120606-0717
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change,2.8.0.v20120606-0717
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change.edit,2.5.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.editor,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,2.8.0.v20120606-0717
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.exporter,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer.ecore,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer.java,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer.rose,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore.editor,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2ecore,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2ecore.editor,2.5.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2xml,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2xml.ui,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ui,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.package.jee,1.5.0.20120131-1544
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.app,1.3.100.v20120522-1841
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.common,3.6.100.v20120522-1841
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.concurrent,1.0.300.v20120522-2049
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.ds,1.4.0.v20120522-1841
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.event,1.2.200.v20120522-2049
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin,2.0.100.v20120606-175127
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.equinox,1.0.400.v20120428-0117
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty,3.0.0.v20120522-1841
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry,1.1.200.v20120522-2049
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet,1.1.300.v20120522-1841
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper,1.0.400.v20120522-2049
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry,1.0.300.v20120522-2049
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.launcher,1.3.0.v20120522-1813
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86,1.1.200.v20120522-1813
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository,1.1.200.v20120430-1959
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.console,1.0.300.v20120429-0125
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core,2.2.0.v20120430-0525
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director,2.2.0.v20120524-0542
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app,1.0.300.v20120428-0517
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery,1.0.200.v20120524-1717
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.compatibility,1.0.101.v20120524-1717
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine,2.2.0.v20120501-1502
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata,2.1.0.v20120430-2001
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository,1.2.100.v20120524-1717
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations,2.2.0.v20120524-0542
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher,1.2.0.v20120428-0117
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse,1.1.0.v20120511-1931
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins,1.1.200.v20120301-2145
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository,2.2.0.v20120524-1945
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools,2.0.100.v20120501-1314
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse,2.1.100.v20120428-0117
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives,1.1.0.v20120524-0542
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf,1.0.100.v20120305-0333
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui,2.2.0.v20120524-0542
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.discovery,1.0.0.v20110808-1657
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.importexport,1.0.1.v20110818-1344
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk,1.0.200.v20120515-1650
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler,1.1.0.v20110815-1744
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite,1.0.400.v20120412-1615
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.preferences,3.5.0.v20120522-1841
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.registry,3.5.200.v20120522-1841
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.security,1.1.100.v20120522-1841
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.security.ui,1.1.100.v20120522-2049
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86,1.0.300.v20120522-2049
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator,1.0.300.v20110815-1744
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.util,1.0.400.v20120522-2049
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef,3.8.0.201206112118
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.help,3.6.0.v20120521-2344
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.help.base,3.6.100.v201206081400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.help.ui,3.5.200.v20120521-2344
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.help.webapp,3.6.100.v20120521-2344
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt,3.8.0.v201206081400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core,3.3.500.v20120522-1651
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core,1.0.400.v20120522-1651
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui,3.3.300.v20120522-1651
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt,1.0.500.v20120522-1651
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool,1.0.101.v20120522-1651
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core,3.8.1.v20120531-0637
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation,1.5.0.v20120523-1543
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug,3.7.100.v20120529-1702
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui,3.6.100.v20120530-1425
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user,3.8.0.v20120606-134218
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit,3.7.100.v20120523-1543
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core,3.7.100.v20120523-1257
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime,3.4.300.v20120523-1257
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime,1.1.200.v20120523-1257
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.launching,3.6.100.v20120523-1953
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.ui,3.8.0.v20120524-1551
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem,2.0.600.v201201051400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jface,3.8.0.v20120521-2329
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jface.databinding,1.6.0.v20120521-2329
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jface.text,3.8.0.v20120531-0600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.branding,1.2.0.v201203150000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.core,1.2.0.v201205240000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.eclipselink.branding,1.2.0.v201203150000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.eclipselink.core,1.2.0.v201203150000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.ui,1.2.0.v201205150000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.utility,2.1.0.v201205020001
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.dbws.eclipselink.branding,1.1.100.v201203150000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.dbws.eclipselink.ui,1.0.200.v201203150000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.doc.user,1.4.2.v201205290002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.branding,1.2.0.v201203150000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core,1.2.0.v201205100000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.schemagen,1.0.200.v201203050000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.branding,1.2.0.v201203150000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.core,1.2.0.v201204160000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.ui,1.3.0.v201204160000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.ui,1.3.0.v201205180000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.branding,3.2.0.v201203150000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core,3.2.0.v201206110000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db,2.1.100.v201203150000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.branding,3.2.0.v201203150000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core,2.2.0.v201205240000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen,2.1.0.v201203150000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.ui,2.2.0.v201205020001
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen,2.2.0.v201205020001
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui,3.2.0.v201205230001
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jsch.core,1.1.400.v20120522-1148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jsch.ui,1.1.400.v20120522-1148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.frameworks,1.1.600.v201204190200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.201.v201108161900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.ui,1.0.200.v201202020230
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ejb.ui,1.1.700.v201201190500
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee,1.1.600.v201205170400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core,1.2.200.v201205030130
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb,1.1.600.v201205030130
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.jca,1.1.600.v201111012200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.navigator.ui,1.1.600.v201203142300
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ui,1.1.600.v201205170400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web,1.1.600.v201203142300
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jee,1.0.500.v201202020745
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui,1.0.500.v201205170400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core,1.4.0.v201205241050
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core,1.0.200.v201205161442
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facesconfig,1.2.100.v2012030703072246
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facesconfig.ui,1.2.100.v201201111516
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsf.ui,1.3.200.v201202131530
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core,1.2.500.v201203071954
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui,1.1.700.v201204260100
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner,1.3.200.v2012030703072246
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.jsp.core,1.2.100.v201112111111
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.core,1.2.302.v20120503_1042
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.preview.adapter,1.1.200.v20120517_1442
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core,1.1.400.v20120418_1501
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui,1.1.300.v20120420_1012
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui,1.1.600.v201202011057
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws,1.0.600.v201108242234
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.annotations.core,1.2.0.v201203272107
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis.consumption.ui,1.0.700.v201204181727
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis.creation.ui,1.0.750.v201204120428
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.consumption,1.0.700.v201204102147
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.consumption.ui,1.1.500.v201204102147
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.creation.ui,1.0.700.v201205041550
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.consumption.core,1.0.200.v201201312103
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.consumption.ui,1.0.200.v201201312103
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.core,1.1.0.v201205012246
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.creation.core,1.0.200.v201205012246
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.creation.ui,1.0.200.v201204221838
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user,1.0.200.v201205231944
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.ui,1.0.200.v201203062228
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.core,1.0.400.v201202152223
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.ui,1.0.500.v201205020140
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.core,1.0.200.v201204172145
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.doc.user,1.0.200.v201205231938
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.dom.integration,1.0.200.v201109042201
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.dom.runtime,1.0.200.v201109042201
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.ui,1.0.200.v201204221614
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils,1.0.200.v201201032002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring,3.6.0.v20120523-1543
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring,3.7.0.v20120523-1543
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core,3.8.0.v20120612-0600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ide,3.8.0.v20120612-0600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ui,3.8.0.v20120612-0600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core,3.8.0.v20120612-0600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net,3.8.0.v20120612-0600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.screenshots,3.8.0.v20120612-0600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui,3.8.0.v20120612-0600
truncated due to SO message limit
```

Comment: Eclipse isn't installed. It's executed.

Comment: its a fair comment, however deleting and putting a new one back then re-installing the SDK has put things in a much better situation now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem though I had all the right requirements.

Java 1.6 and 1.7, Eclipse Indigo (v3.7), ADT v18 and SDK 18 (with Android v4.0.3). I wanted to upgrade to v20 ADT and SDK but Eclipse threw the same bug listed above. I upgraded the SDK manually but Eclipse refused to upgrade. I uninstalled ADT v18 in hope that I could install a fresh ADT v20, but to no avail, even with the ADT v20 download from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html.

Finally, I upgraded to Eclipse Juno (v4.2) and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 10):

There is a hint in this ticket: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290782

Delete all urls from window -> preferences -> Install/Update -> available software sites and retry your update.

Comment: I think that if you're trying to avoid a reinstall, this is a pretty good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the directory where your Eclipse is in is writable or not. For ex, if it's in Program Files, it is not writable.

If yes, then move Eclipse to a writable location, such as My Documents/Eclipse.

Comment: no permission problems from what I could tell. anyway i've started from the ground up now, fingers crossed its all fixed by the morning

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites, find url to ADT Plugin and change https to http (e.g. https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ to http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/). 
When you finalize update operation revert changed url to https. It should help.

Comment: For me, I was having http, and changing to https was the only way to install the update.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me, but I don't understand why. Any idea why it would work with http but not https?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be solved when you update your Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools from revision 19 to revision 20 (using SDK Manager to update). After successful update these tools, you can return to Eclipse and update your ADT plugin.

As it stated here: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Dependencies:

Java 1.6 or higher is required for ADT 20.0.2.
Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6.2) or higher is required for ADT 20.0.2.
ADT 20.0.2 is designed for use with SDK Tools r20.0.1. If you haven't already installed SDK Tools r20.0.1 into your SDK, use the Android SDK Manager to do so.

Bug fixes:

Fixed keybindings in various XML editors for Eclipse 4.x.
Fixed bug when creating layout configurations that already exist.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as moved eclipse to the c:\ drive everything worked OK.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps, worked for me.

- Goto Preferences/install/available software site
- Export all bookmarks
- Remove all bookmarks
- Edit bookmarks.xml and add a backslash at the end of each URL
- Import bookmarks.xml
- Check for updates...

Source: 
http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=120338